# What does operator++ do on a forward iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

From my understand, `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` use forward iterators.

I could do something like this

```
auto it = unordered_map_instance.begin(); 
it++;
```

But I can't do something like this

```
auto it = unordered_map_instance.begin(); 
it = it + 1;
```

I've always thought `++` is simply just incrementing by 1, but that doesn't appear to be so with forward iterators. Could someone explain what `++` does for forward iterators? I can't seem to google this operator. +

Comment: I have understood nothing.

Comment: `operator++` is different than `operator+(int)` The `iterator` overloads the former, but not the latter

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think OP thinks that `it++` is defined as `it = it+1` for iterators.

Comment: A note about [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) seems relevant.

Comment: `++` moves the iterator forward one step. With random access iterators, this is the same as adding one, but not with forward iterators; `+` is only available when it can be executed in constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to [`[iterator.requirements]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/iterator.requirements) from the C++ standard, `iterator` requires the `operator++()` (and `operator++(int)` for most types) to be overloaded. These are not to be confused with `operator+(int)`, which would be the equivalent of your second example. The `++` operator is **not** the same as addition.

As to what the `operator++()` actually does, is it simply moves ahead by one in the list, i.e. to the next element. For example:

```
std::map<int,int> map_instance = { { 1,1 }, {2,2}, {3,3} };
auto it = map_instance.begin(); // it points to {1,1}
it++;  // now it points to {2,2}
```

Incrementing by more than one can be done with [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Comment: `operator+(int)` is not sufficient on it self to achieve `it = it + 1` right? We'd need `operator=` as well?

Comment: @dd22205 you get that from *CopyAssignable*, which is also a requirement of *Iterator*

Comment: Also, in the comments in the snippet, those aren't guaranteed right? `unordered_map_instance.begin()` could point to any of the 3 elements since the container is unordered?

Comment: The reason that `operator+(int)` is not supported for forward iterators is that it cannot be implemented in constant time. For that, you need random access iterators. Using `std::advance` instead of `+` ought to make it clear that this operation could be expensive.

Comment: @dd22205, `begin()` will always be the first element in the list/map/set/vector/etc (or `end()` if the container is empty). My example is technically incorrect, since it assumes the ordering, as if it were a map. For unordered_map, it could be any. I'll update it to `map` to be more clear

Comment: Yes, but the first element isn't necessarily `{1,1}`?

Comment: Makes sense. Also, and this might be getting off topic but why does `operator+(int)` not take in an actual variable for the `int`? How does it know what `it` should be incremented by without a variable? Maybe it'll help to see a reference, but I always have a hard time getting Google to show the correct links when I'm searching for signage

Comment: @dd22205, it does. `operator+(int val)`, but the variable name doesn't matter, so it's often left off when showing signatures.